# maven: add arbitrary file as a servlet context resource

Tags: maven-2, servlets, maven-war-plugin

I have a maven war project which produces webapp.war, and a maven 'skin' project which produces skin.zip (a file full of resources and XML files).  Now I want to add this zip file as a servlet context resource (e.g WEB-INF/skin.zip).

I tried using overlays, but it expands the zip file into WEB-INF instead of placing the un-expanded file there:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <overlays>
                <overlay>
                    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                    <artifactId>skin</artifactId>

                    <type>zip</type>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                </overlay>
            </overlays>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there any way to prevent it from expanding the resource -- or somehow stick the file in there (without using ant-plugin).

Note: `type` is a totally unnecessary and unhelpful configuration element -- it does not tell the plugin how to expand the artifact, as you might expect -- it tells it how to **FIND** it.  For example if you change type from zip to jar, it complains that it can't find the artifact (in the most unhelpful way possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using overlays, but it expands the zip file into WEB-INF

Yes, that's what overlays do, the content is unpacked to be merged with the war. That's just not the right tool in your case.

> Is there any way to prevent it from expanding the resource -- or somehow stick the file in there

I would use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its [`dependency:copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal:

> - `dependency:copy` takes a list of artifacts defined in the plugin configuration section and copies them to a specified location, renaming them or stripping the version if desired. This goal can resolve the artifacts from remote repositories if they don't exist in local.

And bind it on the `prepare-package` phase. Below, some starting point:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-prepare-package</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId><!-- or ${project.groupId} -->
                  <artifactId>skin</artifactId>
                  <version>X.Y.Z</version><!-- or ${project.version} -->
                  <type>zip</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

See [Copying specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) for more examples.

Comment: This works, although the down side of it being copied rather than included as an overlay; is that any current/future overlay-aware IDE plugins (i'm thinking m2eclipse) won't _know_ about the dependency as being a component of a war file -- and thus you get separate deploytime vs. IDE debug/run-time behavior.

Comment: @Justin Ah, I see. I'm afraid the alternative would be to include your skin.zip **in** another archive to get overlays working. That's possible though.